# How to handle url link route in tiny url?

Tags: reactjs

When I enter short url how to redirect it to the corresponding long url after retrieving the original url from server or else on page displaying url doesn't exit.

For example for a given long url

```
www.mysite.com/very-long-url
```

I have it's short url link in database

```
www.mysite.com/shortUrl
```

Now when I enter `www.mysite.com/shortUrl` I should get redirected to long url address and if it doesn't exist then to a page `www.mysite.com/error`.

Comment: Please add more detail; it is not clear what you're asking. Are you trying to implement tinyUrl-like functionality within your own react application, or how to use actual tinyUrl links, or something else?

Comment: @DanielBeck yes